# root UIViewController orientation landscape, touches weird in subviews

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I'm making an application which will be landscape only. Therefore, my root UIViewController is set to be landscape (all xib files I have are landscape orientation).

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

When I try to touch a button in one of the subviews, it does not receive a touch. If I remove the override shown above, the buttons get the touches, but the subview is shown in portrait orientation.

How should I work around this problem?

Thanks & Best Regards,

David

Answer (score 0):

Aside from that, you have to set the supported orientations in your info.plist file.

Its under "Supported interface orientations", with key "UISupportedInterfaceOrientations". Remove the portrait orientations in the list.